# Loading images in HTML by quality

Tags: html, image, loading

Is there a way to load my images in a way their quality get better as they load as opposed to the image being "scanned" or "scrolled" as it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the image as [Progressive JPEG](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html).

I believe that by now all major browsers will show it just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Progressive JPEG is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to preload images before displaying them, this prevents the behaviour you've described. A good article on this can be found [here](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol6/css_no18.htm).